# What are pros/cons of dselect and apt-get?

Tags: debian, apt

I hardly ever hear anyone mention `dselect`, a deprecated package management front-end for Debian. Considering that it still exists as part of [dpkg source](http://packages.debian.org/source/testing/dpkg), it must still have its uses. What are those? How does it compare with `apt-get`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dselect is an interactive dpkg front-end that resolves dependencies and conflicts. It lacks most of apt's advanced features: no differenciation between Suggests/Recommends/Depends, less good dependency and conflict resolution, no support for multiple sources of packages, no [apt pinning/preferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool#APT_pinning), no automatically-installed package mark, …

(This is from memory. Actually dselect can now use apt backends for some functions, at least it can download from apt's `sources.list`.)

Dselect got a lot of hate simply from having unusual key bindings. I think your question will bring out unfond memories in some people.

I suppose dselect can still be useful if you want an interactive package selector with smaller memory consumption than apt.

Comment: Heh... Unfond memories?  I sure remember the thrill switching from slack to debian... dselect... awesome!  Anyhow, most of the things you mention here were outdated ten years ago.  It does suggest/recommend/depend on packages. Dselect uses apt-get and its sources.list with as many sources you like.  Dselect won't use less memory than apt-get tho since it calls apt-get for about everything.  You're right about the pinning tho ;-)

Comment: While I haven't used it in a couple of years `dselect` is still one of my most favourite package manager front ends and I loved those key bindings. I actually loath `aptitude` and still prefer `dselect`.

Answer (score 1):

Deselect doesn't have any of the wonderful dependency resolution, but you can kind of think of deselect as a curses based "synaptic". However, you only want to make selections with deselect; don't actually do the installation.

After making selections run this:

```
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Best of both worlds.

Comment: Aptitude is even better ;)

Comment: I'm old school.

Comment: @bahamat Why use `dselect` instead of `aptitude` for selection?

Comment: @Tshepang I don't, I use apt-get. Although I do use `dpkg --set-selections` to set a large list of packages that I want then use `apt-get dselect-upgrade` to install them. This is extremely handy for automating system set up on a large scale.

Comment: can u check the grammar on the last sentence; it's hard to parse :)

Comment: I'm not sure what doesn't make sense.

Comment: I looks like the last sentence should be split into 2. Also, can u explain why u discourage installing with dselect.

Comment: I don't discourage it per sé. I don't particularly care for package menus. I already know what I want and don't need to browse. If I'm searching I much prefer apt-cache. But if you like to browse, then by all means. That's why there are different options. For a beginner, aptitude is much easier. But for an advanced user dselect is chock full of single keystroke commands and other difficult to discover goodies.

Comment: You're wrong on all accounts.  After selecting packages, dselect shows suggestions, recommendations and depends.  Also, using "install" from the dselect menu actually calls `apt-get dselect-upgrade`.

Comment: God I hate `aptitude`, I still wish `dselect` was further evolved :(

Answer (score 1):

For an `aptitude`-based package-{backup, restore}, see [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/61472/95940). For {`deborphan`-based package backup, `aptitude`-based package restore}, see [advice from Bogdan Tokovenko (et al)](http://bogdan.org.ua/2013/10/18/saving-restoring-list-of-packages-installed-on-debian-using-aptitude-deborphan.html) .

Comment: I can vouch for aptitude and for deborphan. However you do not mention debfoster, which is a lifesaver to prune unwanted default packages or packages installed by mistake. In my opinion, the three are indispensable for any serious sysadmin [maybe except nowadays with the remote trends of Ansible, puppet and the likes]. I would also mention here, besides the link, that aptitude has a much more modern interactive interface dselect-like.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro: Is the following quote (from [this official-looking site](http://www.fruit.je/debfoster/)) not correct? `As of 2006-01-01, debfoster is officially deprecated: aptitude does the same stuff as debfoster but [is] integrated into [APT].`

Comment: Now that you mention it I do remember something about being obsolete. Thanks for pointing that out. I will investigate how to do it with aptitude, as the functionality is *very* convenient. Changed my post.

Comment: However, and I have thought it what happens is that aptitude also maintains a DB of interdependencies like debfoster. What I do find useful in debfoster is not the houseking (that aptitude provides), it is deleting the DB, and do an audit of the system. It is excellent to prepare a base image, or to clean systems you inherited.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this is a fairly old question. To answer it in a more modern tone, dselect is fairly old and obsolete. aptitude is far more consistent into evaluating dependencies than dselect and apt-get, and as a bonus, it you call aptitude without arguments, you have a dselect-like interface that works so much better.

aptitude does not come installed by default, and in Debian you have to do:

```
apt-get install aptitude
```

Comment: See [this comment above](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/what-are-pros-cons-of-dselect-and-apt-get/243510#comment418407_243510) regarding `debfoster`.